# What does operator void* () mean?

Tags: c++

I googled, but didn't find a clear answer. Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator void* () {
         return ptr;
    }

private:
    void *ptr;
};
```

I understand what `void* operator()` is. Is the above operator the same thing in a different syntax? If not, what is it? And how can I use that operator to get the `ptr`?

Comment: Note that your current code has a typo, `opeator` lacks an r

Comment: @StephenTG Thanks. Modified

Comment: It's a cast operator.  http://ideone.com/k1EiJF

Comment: @Chad - it's a **conversion** operator. Some conversions are done with a cast, some are not.

Comment: This might be an attempt at the Safe Bool Idiom. See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool2.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No they are two different operators. The `operator void*` function is a type casting function, while `operator()` is a function call operator.

The first is used when you want to convert an instance of `Foo` to a `void*`, like e.g.

```
Foo foo;
void* ptr = foo;  // The compiler will call `operator void*` here
```

The second is used as a function:

```
Foo foo;
void* ptr = foo();  // The compiler calls `operator()` here
```

Comment: So `operator()` can be implemented to provide callable objects?

Comment: Will that enable implicit conversion? e.g. Can I safely pass Foo to a function like `void bar ([anytype])` if I implement `operator [anytype]()` in Foo?

Comment: @YZ.learner Besides the implicit casting in the specification (like `short` to `int` etc.) you can get implicit casting two other ways: By having the "destination" class contain a non-explicit constructor taking the "source" type, or by having a casting operator like in your example.

Answer (score 5):

That function defines what happens when the object is converted to a void pointer, here it evaluates to the address the member `ptr` points to.

It is sometimes useful to define this conversion function, e.g. for boolean evaluation of the object.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() : ptr(0) {
        std::cout << "I'm this: " << this << "\n";
    }
    operator void* () {
        std::cout << "Here, I look like this: " << ptr << "\n";
        return ptr;
    }
private:
    void *ptr;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    // convert to void*
    (void*)foo;
    // as in:
    if (foo) { // boolean evaluation using the void* conversion
        std::cout << "test succeeded\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "test failed\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out
I'm this: 0x7fff6072a540
Here, I look like this: 0
Here, I look like this: 0
test failed
```

See also:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: "otherwise it'd be the address of the object itself, this." -- No, it wouldn't. I think you're confusing the object with a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 1):

It's a type conversion operator. It is used whenever an object of class `Foo` is casted (converted) to `void*`. It is indeed not the same as `void* operator()`.